# React JS Async function works properly in its own file, but not when exported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I've tried for hours on my own + more on stackoverflow to try to solve this but to no avail.

So I'm trying to use travel time as a part of a calculation I'm doing with the front-end logic in react, and while it works in its own file, I get an axios error when exporting it to a separate component and trying to log the data there.
Here is the child component, just a function that takes origin and destination and returns the travel duration:

```
import axios from "axios";

const distanceMatrix = async (origins, destinations) => {
  const API_KEY = "A***********************Y";
  const url = new URL(
    "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json"
  );
  const params = new URLSearchParams({
    key: API_KEY,
    origins: origins,
    destinations: destinations,
    mode: "driving",
    departure_time: Date.now(),
    traffic_model: "pessimistic",
    units: "imperial",
  });

  url.search = params;
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    return response.data.rows[0].elements[0].duration_in_traffic.value;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export default distanceMatrix;
```

But when I export/import to use in a search form, I get this error from the log:

> AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

Here is my form that imports for reference:

```
import distanceMatrix from "../calculations/distancematrix/distanceMatrix";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const SearchForm = () => {
  const [origin, setOrigin] = useState("");
  const [destination, setDestination] = useState("");

  const handleOrigin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setOrigin(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleDestination = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setDestination(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    (async () => {
      const duration = await distanceMatrix(origin, destination);
      console.log(duration);
    })();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="origin"
        placeholder="Origin"
        value={origin}
        onChange={handleOrigin}
      ></input>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="destination"
        placeholder="Destination"
        value={destination}
        onChange={handleDestination}
      ></input>
      <button type="submit">Search Route</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default SearchForm;
```

Thanks to anyone who can help.

I want to just be able to print to the console for now to make sure the function works within the other component.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who may come after: It looks like the issue was specific to making an API request through my browser, which explains why it worked in VSCode but not through Axios. To fix it I installed this: [Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf) plugin, followed the 1 minute video directions and it worked immediately after. Hopefully this saved you the 5 hours I spent troubleshooting...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).